# One to many matching, using Hall's theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I'm having a difficult time finding the neccessary and sufficient condition in the question and would love some help, I thought I had it but found a counter example for my "proof". The question is:

Given a bipartite graph, find a neccessary and sufficient condition for that it would be possible to match every vertex on one side, to two vertices on the other side, that would belong only to him.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? The "obvious" step of duplicating one side seems to work, so where are you stuck?

Comment: I thought about doubling the edges that represent the "one side".
but I couldn't understand what will be the condition and how it will translate back to the normal graph?

Comment: Now posted, for no good reason, and with no notice to either site, at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358562/expanding-halls-theorem

Comment: I apologize, I thought these are separate sites, and I didn't recieved an answer here, though it is voted like I have, but I'm positive its flawed unfortunatley.

Comment: They are separate sites, which is one reason why you **don't** post the same question to both, at least not until after several days have passed without an answer at one of them, and it's why even in that case, you leave a link to each site at the other site. You need to have some patience – you can't expect @Calvin to be at your beck & call 24/7, he may well come back to reply to your comments if you just give him a chance.

Answer (score 4):

Given the bipartite graph $ U \times V$, it would be possible to match every vertex on one side, to two vertices on the other side, if and only if

> Given the bipartite graph $ ( U + U') \times V$ (where the edges of $U' \times V$ are exactly what you think) ...

$ $

> has a perfect matching.
>  Now convert this back to $ U \times V$.

$ $

**Hint:** It has a very similar flavor to Hall Marriage Theorem. You should be able to guess what the (obvious) change is.

> Given any $ u$ vertices in $U$, the image in $V$ has size $ \geq 2u$.
>  Given any $2v$ vertices in $V$, the image in $U$ has size $ \geq v$.

Comment: I see you wrote here to find exactly where I'm stuck, how can I translate it back?

Comment: @Blur I just added the answer in. I've been scolded for giving answers when OP has shown no work, so I'm not writing anything else unless you show some work.

Comment: I just need you (if you can) to answer the original question, because I already had the construction figured out. The only thing I'm not sure about is translating it back to my original graph.

Comment: @Blur I've given the condition in the 3rd hidden text. If you're having difficulty proving that it is necessary and sufficient, show your work.

Comment: Oh I missed that. Not used to this hidden layers :-)
Will now work on it. Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI If you click on the hidden layers, the text will stay revealed. That helps when working through multiple of them.

Comment: Is it possible you may have mistakenly wrote edges instead of vertices in your condition? and are these two conditions or one? can you please clarify?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: @Blur Yes, should be vertices. Both conditions have to be satisfied, IE "has double matching if and only if (1 and 2)".

Comment: Isn't this condition enough:
For any X subset of U: NG(X)>=2*|X|
?

Comment: @Blur Given that you're merely quoting the MO result, and I see no effort from you, I'm not engaging further as that's not what the MSE community wants.

Comment: I'm not qouting anyone. this is my solution. I'm uploading it right now as an answer. I would appreciate if you take a look at it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

###### Neccessary condition:

Let $G=\{V_1 \cup V_2, E\}$ be a bipartite graph where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are his sides. It is given that for any $v$ element of $V_1$ we can match $2$ neighbours from $V_2$ that are only his.
Thus for any $A$ subset of $V_1$, $|N_G(A)| \geq 2|A|$.

###### Sufficient condition:

We assume that for any $A$ subset of $V_1$, $|N_G(A)| \geq 2|A|$.
We do the following construction of $G'=\{V_1' \cup V_2, E'\}$ where $V_1'= V_1 \cup V_1''$ and $E'= E \cup E''$:

1. for each vertex $v$ in $V_1$ we clone a vertex $v''$ that is an element of $V_1''$.
2. for any edge $\{v,u\}$ where $v$ is in $V_1$ and $u$ is in $V_2$, we connect an edge $\{v'',u\}$ that is an element of $E''$ where $v''$ is in $V_1''$ and $u$ is in $V_2$.

Now, because we cloned vertices in side $V_1$ and for any new cloned vertex we connected an edge from it to all of its origin's neighbours, and from our first assumption we get that for any $A$ subset of $V_1'$: $|N_G(A)| \geq |A|$.
That means that our $G'$ satisfies Hall's condition; thus it has a matching that covers $V_1'$. Now in $V_1'$ any vertex is represented twice, and therefore you can match for each $v$ of $V_1$ two neighbours that are only his from $V_2$.

Comment: I suggest you put aome time into learning how to format mathematics on this website. The Help menu will lead you to tips for this.

Comment: Ok sir. Thank you.